# Convert all non numeric column in numeric sklearn python

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to convert all non-numeric column into numeric datatype but it through an error

TypeError: argument must be a string or number

```
for column in clean_df.columns:
  if clean_df[column].dtype == np.number:
    continue
  clean_df[column] = LabelEncoder.fit_transform(clean_df[column])
```

TypeError: fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: @FrancoPiccolo in the last line

Comment: maybe try fit_transform(clean_df[column].values)

Comment: Ensted of LabelEncoder() when I used LabelEncoder then I get 

TypeError: fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the column to like (.toarray()). Which returns an array with same shape and same representing data.

```
for column in clean_df.columns:
    if clean_df[column].dtype == np.number:
       continue
    clean_df[column] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(clean_df[column]).toarray()
```

Comment: Once try to use OneHotEncoder available in sklearn.preprocessing replacing the label encoder()

Answer (score 0):

```
    import numpy as np
    X = clean_df.select_dtypes(include=[np.object])
    #For loop to loop one by one with col type object
    for col in X.columns:
        X[col]=pd.Categorical(X[col],categories=clean_df[col].dropna().unique())
        #creating dummy variable
        X_col = pd.get_dummies(X[col])
        X = X.drop(col,axis=1)
        X_col.columns = X_col.columns.tolist()
        frames = [X_col, X] 
        X = pd.concat(frames,axis=1)
```

You can try this!